# How many times does Dangerous Sorcery apply when the spell rolls several times for damage?

Tags: spells, feats, pathfinder-2e-playtest

I'm confused regarding the interaction between *[Dangerous Sorcery](https://%5BDangerous%20Sorcery%5D%5B1%5D)* and spells like *Magic Missiles*.

> **[Dangerous Sorcery](https://%5BDangerous%20Sorcery%5D%5B1%5D):**
> When you cast a non-cantrip spell that deals damage and that doesn't have a duration, you gain a conditionnal bonus to that spell's damage equal to that spell's level

---

> **Magic Missile:**
> You send a dart of force streaking toward a creature that you can see. It automatically hits and deals 1d4+1 force damage. When Casting this Spell, you can increase the casting by a Material Casting action, a Somatic Casting action, or both. For each component you add, increase the number of missiles you shoot by one. You choose the target for each missile individually.

Assuming a first level Sorcerer, with the [Dangerous Sorcery](https://%5BDangerous%20Sorcery%5D%5B1%5D) feat, casting Magic Missile, would the damage be:

*Number of missiles x (1d4 + 1) + 1 ([Dangerous Sorcery](https://%5BDangerous%20Sorcery%5D%5B1%5D))* // (3d4+3+1)

**or**

*Number of missiles x (1d4 + 1 + 1([Dangerous Sorcery](https://%5BDangerous%20Sorcery%5D%5B1%5D)))* // (3d4+3+3)

**TL;DR: Does [Dangerous Sorcery](https://%5BDangerous%20Sorcery%5D%5B1%5D) apply once for the whole spell, or each time damage is rolled for the spell?**

<sub>1: I did look into the matter (simple google search return exact query) but the answers I found are either old or confused/opinion-based</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You only apply that once

The wording on the feat means that you increase the spell's damage using it, meaning that it will increase the total damage caused by the spell only once, and it will apply to a single target if it is not an area spell.

> When you cast a non-cantrip spell that deals damage and that doesn’t have a duration, you gain a conditional bonus to **that spell’s damage** equal to the spell’s level.

This was [clarified](https://paizo.com/community/blog/v5748dyo5lkxh&page=5?Sorcerer-Class-Preview#222) and then [confirmed](https://paizo.com/community/blog/v5748dyo5lkxh&page=5?Sorcerer-Class-Preview#238) by **Mark Seifter** (developer):

> *Is there any precedent for ruling it at "treat all simultaneous hits against the same creature as single damage source if from one spell, hits not against the same creature are multiple iterations of the damage"?*
>
> *Thematically it's a bit wibbly but it seems like it should play closer to intended, and against resistances and weaknesses more like Double Slice.*
>
> **That's essentially what I have mocked up in a file of possible clarifications.**